# How to add column values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, sum

This is my table data `Student`

[image]

And this is my query --

```
SELECT id, SUM( maths + chemistry + physics ) AS total, maths, chemistry, physics
FROM `student`
```

but it is throwing a single row --

```
id  total   maths   chemistry   physics
118     760     55  67  55
```

although i want to apply sum for all ids ....let me know how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Sum is a aggregate function. You dont need to use it. This is the simple query -

```
select *,(maths + chemistry + physics ) AS total FROM `student`
```

Answer (score 19):

Tip: If one of the fields has the possibility to be NULL, then use [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) to default these to 0, otherwise `total` will result in NULL.

```
SELECT *, (
    COALESCE(maths, 0) +
    COALESCE(chemistry, 0) +
    COALESCE(physics, 0)
) AS total 
FROM `student`
```

Comment: is there an easier way if you have lots of columns you want to add than this? Maybe a database setting?

Comment: @dasLort consider changing your table schema to be INT NOT NULL for example and a default of 0?

Answer (score 11):

If you're requiring to get total marks of each student, then `SUM` is not what you'd be needing.

```
SELECT id,
    (maths+chemistry+physics) AS total,
    maths,
    chemistry,
    physics
FROM `student`
```

Will do the job just fine.

Comment: another fascinating answer..you guys are awesome....very helpful platform for a learner :)

Answer (score 9):

You don't need use `SUM` for this operation. Try this query:

```
SELECT id, ( maths + chemistry + physics ) AS total, maths, chemistry, physics
FROM `student`
```

Answer (score 1):

The sum function in MySQL works in the sense that it gives you the sum of values in a column from your select statement. If you need to sum values from a row in your query, then just use plus (`+`) What you need is this query :

```
SELECT id, (`maths` +`chemistry`+`physics`) AS `total`, `maths`, `chemistry`, `physics`
FROM `student`;
```

This will give you the results you need.

Comment: backtick before FROM is typo, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

All aggregate function works on rows specified by rowname and group by operation. You need operation on individual rows which is not an option for any aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, ( maths + chemistry + physics ) AS total, maths, chemistry, physics
FROM `student`
```

You are done. Thanks