# How to add values from multiple tuples in a MySQL database and fetch them with php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database tables

```
     1. graduate_survey
     G_id(pk),PO1,PO2

     2. Alumni_survey
     A_id(pk),PO1,PO2
```

Suppose i have inserted values in both the tables. Now i have to add the values of PO1, PO2 from graduate_survey with PO1,PO2 of Alumni_survey. How to add them with the help of MySQL query? And how to store the new value in an another table with the help of php?

Comment: Please provide an example. It is unclear if you want to add the values from certain rows with a certain relation or all from both tables.

Comment: i have to add all from both tables. Suppose PO1 and PO2 from graduate_survey have values 80 and 90 and PO1 and PO2 from Alumni_survey have values 70,80... i have to add PO1 from graduate_survey with PO1 from Alumni_survey and same procedure in case of PO2.

Comment: @DebasishChoudhury Read into mysql joins https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html and addition operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387061/how-to-add-column-values-in-mysql and then you will be able to do what you want. For the PHP part. Simply read into PHP database connections and how to fire queries. See http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(t.P01) AS total_P01, SUM(t.P02) AS total_P02
    FROM (SELECT P01, P02 FROM graduate_survey
          UNION ALL
          SELECT P01, P02 FROM Alumni_survey) t
```

This works. Based on: [How can I sum columns across multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432178/how-can-i-sum-columns-across-multiple-tables-in-mysql)
*I'm not marking it as duplicate because the resource is for one value, here are two.*

Adding results of type DECIMAL(10,6) from 2 real tables with 18k+57k entries the query takes about 0.15s to complete.

Part 2: INSERT

Assuming your new table has AUTO INCREMENT on T_id (pk) and you have fetched the previous result with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` into $row:

```
$query_string = "INSERT INTO Total_survey 
 SET P01 = '".floatval($row['total_P01'])."', 
 P02 = '".floatval($row['total_P02'])."' ";
```

- or intval() if your results are integers.

Edit: For 3 tables:

```
SELECT SUM(t.P01) AS total_P01, SUM(t.P02) AS total_P02
    FROM (SELECT P01, P02 FROM graduate_survey
          UNION ALL
          SELECT P01, P02 FROM Alumni_survey
          UNION ALL
          SELECT P01, P02 FROM faculty_survey) t
```

But I don't think it is a good idea. You have tables with the same structure  holding similar data. A better approach would be to make just 1 more column in one table and write for each record is it for graduates, alumnies or faculties. Holding 3 separate tables for this job just makes your database structure hard to understand and hard to use. You can make these two tables:

```
Survey: id(pk), group_id(int), PO1, PO2
```

and a description table:

```
Groups: group_id(pk), group_name(varchar)
```

This way you can have unlimited number of survey groups, you can extend their number dynamically from your program and handle their data much easier.

Comment: After adding when we get the new values of PO1 and PO2 can we store the new value of PO1 and PO2 in another table say Total_survey(T_id (pk), PO1,PO2)?

Comment: If I want the result from three tables say one more table  faculty_survey where f_id(pk),PO1,PO2 then how can do this?

Comment: after adding i need average of the value and then i have to store it in another table total_survey. how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO connection:

```
$sql = 'SELECT gs.G_id G_id, as_.A_id A_id, (gs.PO1 + gs.PO2 + as_.PO1 + as_.PO2) total from graduate_survey gs, Alumni_survey as_';
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name(G_id, A_id, total) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
$conn->beginTransaction();
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
   $stmt->bindValue(1, $row['G_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindValue(2, $row['A_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindValue(3, $row['total'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->commit();
```